# Issue while building Windows Azure PowerShell CmdLet for Node.js/PHP

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to build the Windows Azure PowerShell cmdlet, but facing issue while loading the cmdlet. I have followed the below steps:

1. Cloned the latest code from master branch https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools
2. Build the solution WindowsAzurePowershell.sln using VS 2010 SP1 Ultimate [I have Windows Azure SDK 1.7, VS 2010 tools for Windows Azure and WIX installed]
3. After building the solution, opened the folder C:\repo\Windows-Azure-SDK-Nodejs-Git\azure-sdk-tools\Package\Debug and tried to load the cmdlet by running the command:
   Get-ChildItem '.*.psd1' | ForEach-Object {Import-Module $_}

And got the below error. Could someone please help me to resolve this issue?

If I install the official cmdlet bits using WebPI, everything works fine. But the cmdlet installed using the msi I built failed to load with the same error.

## Error:

PS C:\repo\Windows-Azure-SDK-Nodejs-Git\azure-sdk-tools\Package\Debug> Get-ChildItem '.*.psd1' | ForEach-Object
{Import-Module $*} > error.txt
Import-Module : Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in C:\Interop-TFS\Windows-Azure-SDK-Nodejs-Git\azure-sdk-tools\Pack
age\Debug\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceManagement.dll because of the following error: Unable to load one or
 more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Loader Exceptions:
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31
bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31
bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31
bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31
.....
bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31
bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:57
+ Get-ChildItem '.*.psd1' | ForEach-Object {Import-Module <<<<  $*} > error.txt
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Import-Module], PSSnapInException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSnapInLoadFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Go to Control Panel and every thing related with "Windows Azure Powershell *", uninstall all.
- Now install [Windows Azure Powershell CMdlets](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9811175&clcid=0x409)
- Verify you have powershell installed @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell (You will all the dll in this folder which result missing in your problem case)
- Now open a Windows Powershell prompt in admin mode
- Use this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156055) and follow the process to verify that you can access to Windows Azure Management Services (This is just to verify that you have all modules needed in your machine)
- Now try whatever you wanted to try and there should not be any issue.

Comment: Thanks Avkash. I got the issue solved, the references in the project (both master and dev branch)  point to signed DLLs. I have disabled strong name verification in dev machine, now I can load the modules and debug.

Comment: I am glad that your problem is resovled. Good luck for your next problem ahead.

Comment: Thanks Avkash. Reason is I want to debug and understand the code flow, trying to understand the implementation :)

Comment: @Anu Thomas Chandy, I have the same problem, trying to import the custom-built PowerShell modules. Please, could you share how you resolved your issue ?